# Unable to build yesod app: ``strip.exe: unable to rename``

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I'm trying to build an application using Yesod on Windows. I installed the haskell platform, and then Yesod using cabal. The command `yesod init` works, but after installing the dependencies cabal exits with the following message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring yosog-0.0.0...
Building yosog-0.0.0...
Failed to install yosog-0.0.0
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Users\dna\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\yosog-0.0.0.log ):
Installing library in
C:\Users\dna\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\yosog-0.0.0
Installing executable(s) in C:\Users\dna\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\mingw\bin\strip.exe: unable to rename 'C:\Users\dna\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\yosog.exe'; reason: File exists
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
yosog-0.0.0 failed during the final install step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Do you have any idea about what can be causing this error?

The version of the haskel platform I have installed ships with `ghc` 4.8.3, and `cabal-install` version 1.18.1.3 of the Cabal library.

Comment: Looks to me like the binary can't be installed because one with the same name already exists...

Comment: I've checked the path stated in the error message but there is no such binary....

Comment: How odd... The only other possibility I can think of is something strange with file permissions, or antivirus software blocking the operation... Unless the error message is actually caused by some unrelated problem.

Comment: I'm installing yesod in another windows systems and I run into problems with ``ld``. This is due to having two versions of MinGW installed on my system (the one I had installed before haskell-platform (HP), and the one bundled with HP). 

I don't have this problem anymore, but maybe the conflicting versions of ``ld`` were causing it.